# delete outliers from all columns of a dataframe in r

Tags: r, outliers

I'm trying to delete outliers from my dataset, using iqr. I got iqr value for each column in my dataframe and now i want to exclude from the dataframe all the values that are outliers.
My code is:

```
> q1 <- colwise(quantile)(completeData,  probs = c(.25))
> q2 <- colwise(quantile)(completeData,  probs = c(.75))
> IQR <- q2 - q1
> IQR
  MinTemp MaxTemp Rainfall Evaporation Sunshine WindGustSpeed WindSpeed9am WindSpeed3pm Humidity9am Humidity3pm Pressure9am Pressure3pm Cloud9am Cloud3pm Temp9am Temp3pm RainToday Date Location
1     9.2    10.3      2.2         4.4      7.1            19            8           11          26          31         9.6         9.7        5        4     9.3     9.9         1 1537       25
  WindGustDir WindDir3pm RainTomorrow
1           9          8            1
```

Now that i have iqr values for each variable in the dataframe i want to exclude outliers this way:

```
completeData <- subset(completeData, completeDat > (q1 - 1.5*IQR) & completeData < (q2+1.5*IQR))
```

This last line is just to let you understand the idea. The code of the last line is not working and i just want something that can help me delete all outliers from each column of the data frame.

Thanks in advance to who will help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing outliers from the dataset I'll suggest to turn them to `NA` since you can have variable number of outliers in each column which will give you different number of values.

```
completeData <- lapply(completeData, function(x) {
  q1 <- quantile(x, .25)
  q2 <- quantile(x, .75)
  IQR <- q2 - q1
  replace(x, x < (q1 - 1.5*IQR) | x > (q2+1.5*IQR), NA)
})
```

Comment: thank you for the help! but if i want to delete it how can i do it? this code will work for each column of the dataframe taking in mind the different iqr for eache variable? really appreciate your help

Comment: how can i handle different number of values and then get a dataframe with same number of rows for each variable?

Comment: @bek99 Can you provide an example data and show expected output for it so that it is clear what you want to do.

Comment: my data is the weatherAUS dataset of Rain in Australia in kaggle. the desired output should be of removing all outliers that we found with iqr for each variable in the dataframe. So i did it in python with this code: # Detecting outliers with IQR
Q1 = MiceImputed.quantile(0.25);
Q3 = MiceImputed.quantile(0.75);
IQR = Q3 - Q1;
print(IQR); # Removing outliers from dataset
MiceImputed = MiceImputed[~((MiceImputed < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(MiceImputed > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)];

Answer (score 0):

To delete the outliers, try the following.
It defines a function to be applied `colwise` and uses the result to subset the data.

```
library(plyr)

outl <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE){
  qq <- quantile(x, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm)
  iqr <- diff(qq)
  x > qq[1] - 1.5*iqr & x < qq[2] + 1.5*iqr
}

which_out <- colwise(outl)(completeData)
```

This is to delete the rows with at least one outlier.

```
subset(completeData, rowSums(which_out) == ncol(which_out))
```

And this is to keep the rows with at least one outlier. Tested with the data below.

```
subset(completeData, rowSums(which_out) < ncol(which_out))
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4
#33          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1
#34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2
#61          5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0
```

**Test data**

```
data(iris, package = "datasets")
completeData <- iris[-5]
```

Comment: is this the same of doing this in python? # Removing outliers from dataset
MiceImputed = MiceImputed[~((MiceImputed < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) |(MiceImputed > (Q3 + 1.5 * IQR))).any(axis=1)]

Comment: @bek99 See what's in matrix `which_out`. It's a logical matrix with each column giving whether the entry is an outlier or not. Then you can use the matrix to keep or remove what you want, the two examples with `rowSums` are not the only uses for `which_out` possible.